# Flutter, Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}

HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
```

Many answers have answered as above and I have tried many times

I have 2 Android devices and 2 iPhone devices, and actually 1 devices are in use. (I use them they don`t need Wifi)

```
Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake
```

It seems to have something to do with wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to set your HttpOverrides? In your main set it like this:

```
HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
```

Comment: Ahh yah sorry I put the wrong one. That is not working too I edited